# Android Service that works only when app is closed

Tags: android, service

As the title, I need that an Android Service - that periodically calls a web service - does the job only when the app is closed. When the app is running (don't matter if in background or foreground) the Service must be stopped.

How I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: call startService/stopService in onDestroy/onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one `Activity` as an entry point for your app it would be very easy. This `Activity` will be the destroyed at end when user leave your app, so overriding `onDestroy()` and launching `Service` from there will do the job. When the same `Activity` starts you can request stopping your `Service` inside `onCreate()` of the Activity.

Comment: Yes but there is no guarantee that your onDestroy method will be called at all.

Comment: If your Activity dies Service will die too, unless it's running is separate process. You could try start service in onPause.

Comment: I run the activity in a separate process, and I need to know when application is closed, so I can launch the service. When my app is running the GPS is on (is a GPS app). When the user close the app, I need to start a service that use the Google Location Service.

Comment: Then start service from Activity.onPause checking if activity is finishing, otherwise it is simply going to another activity.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, can you provide some example code?

Comment: Call isFinishing() inside activity's onPause(). If it's true, start your service. It's that simple. Use activity's onCreate() to stop service.